# flutter test calls dart:js_interop and fails

Tags: flutter, testing, mockito, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to start with unit testing in my flutter project, but am not able to go ahead because of a dart:js_interop error. I've tried creating MockProviders and MockUsers but I still get the error. Attaching the screenshot of the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwsZv.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.